# Have genetic algorithms been applied to Open Data?

Tags: data.gov, big-data

I have become very interested in [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) or **GAs** (which are not necessarily related in any way to genetics or genomics; see link). This algorithmic method of searching is very well-suited to large datasets. There are Open Source projects like the [Encog Machine Learning Framework](https://github.com/encog) that implement GAs. Wikipedia also makes claims about the wide range of fields that GAs have been applied to,

> "Genetic algorithms find application in bioinformatics, phylogenetics,
>   computational science, engineering, economics, chemistry,
>   manufacturing, mathematics, physics, pharmacometrics and other fields."

I am wondering if there have been any studies that have applied GAs to Open Data. [Manufacturing](https://explore.data.gov/catalog/raw?category=Manufactures&utf8=%E2%9C%93) datasets are available on the [Data.gov](http://www.data.gov/) website, and I'm sure there are datasets out there somewhere for each of those other fields. I realize that not all research publications can be accessed for free, but I'm happy with just abstractions or summaries of projects.

**Have any studies applied GAs to Open Data? If so, please provide pointers to them in your answer.**

Comment: I think this is a great question. I wonder why there are at least two down-votes. SE usually posts a quick reminder to people who down-vote a question or answer that they should really consider adding a comment (or maybe even edit the question as @JeanneHolm did) so as to help improve the question. This is more important with a new beta site than any other circumstances, so I encourage people who down-vote to think hard about how they could elaborate on their disapproval with a comment or an edit.

Comment: I agree completely. If this question is out of scope, I would understand why it was downvoted. I can't understand what's wrong with my question without an explanation. The SE format only works when people communicate. Edit: Thanks for your edit, I didn't see it until now.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this answers the question, but there are two aspects: (1) using algorithms to analyze the holdings in a data catalog or a large (big) dataset; and (2) gathering data around genetics and genomics.

(1) There are many tools and programs underway on data analytics. Check out a large solicitation from [NSF](http://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=504767) and an interagency [big data initiative](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/microsites/ostp/big_data_press_release.pdf) that references useful sites at the end.

(2) There is a growing set of data on Data.gov related to genetics and genomics, with particular recent emphasis on agriculture ([Agriculture.Data.gov](http://Agriculture.Data.gov)). And, [open access to federally funded research data](http://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2013/02/22/expanding-public-access-results-federally-funded-research) is a new directive from the White House in addition to the [Executive Order on Open Data](http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2013/05/09/executive-order-making-open-and-machine-readable-new-default-government-).  [Research.Data.gov](http://Research.Data.gov) is starting to categorize and organize data related to that latter directive.

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov)

Comment: This is really awesome, but I am looking for research that has applied a pretty specific type of algorithm. I don't mean research on genetic *data*, but research that used genetic *algorithms*. I apologize for the confusion.